# What does "most natural codomain" mean?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

I am given a function $f(x,y) = (2y, \frac{1}{x})$. And I am asked: "What is the most natural codomain of $f$?". What does it mean for codamain to be "most natural"? Is the most natural codomain $ran(f) = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)\times\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$?
Thank you!

Comment: Where were you asked this? Frankly to me, it seems like a weird question... Probably their asking for the codomain if the domain is $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @QiZhu This is one of my homework question for Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning course . I am just given the function and no domain is given.

Comment: There's a mathematical definition of *natural* but this usage is more idiomatic.  The instructor means “obvious.”  Unfortunately, what's obvious to the instructor is often not obvious to the student.  Talk to the instructor.

Comment: I think they are probably going for $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the natural codomain. When you first see that function, the one of the first things you think is "the outputs of $f$ live in $\mathbb{R}^2$."

Comment: @fafushara.  I'm shocked that modern teaching of math has been so watered down.

Comment: I agree with William Elliot. Not even a domain is given - what if $x$ and $y$ were apples and bananas? What should the student even learn from this question?